# Node Debug large Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

In node i am trying ot debug through node-inspector.  I start a new server (`node-inspector &`).  I start node with `--debug-brk`.

my array has about 3k entries in it, each being an array of about 10 elements (30k integers total).

The debugger (opened in chrome) completely chunks.  Just has such a hard time doing any form of debugging when that table is within local or closure memory.  Any ways of speeding things up?  Is this a memory problem with node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: this happens because of "Scope Variables" window - `node-inspector` updates locals on each step which in your example is the reason why it's so slow. I suggest to use console debugger for that part of code (and try to reduce large array scope as much as possible)*

Don't add the whole array to watch window or console - use individual elements or `array.slice(1100, 1200)` - to get small window, 100 elements in this example

It requires quite a lot of data transfer over the wire on each debugger step to fully mirror this array

Comment: There is only one problem.  Its not that i am trying to view that information, if its contained within Closure or local scope it is automatically pulled in, thus causing massive lag (and 30k integers is very small, about 1 Mb (yes i mean 'b') so i don't see why this would be an issue (unless it happens to be 1992)

Comment: Can you paste  a self contained example? I'll try  to debug debuger

Comment: You right. node-inspector mirrors all scope variables because of "scope variables" window. I don't think there exist good solution with node-inspector (except for modifying source and disabling local vars).  "break" event in debugger wire protocol sends only array of frames (which is usually quite lightweight) I was able to debug example just fine in node.js built in console debugger

Comment: Sorry Andrey for not getting back to you, been at work all day.  If you still want an example its literally this ez.

`arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) { arr.push(i); }` that will choke things up

Comment: Yes, I did exactly the same example (but with 1m array instead of 5k )